# Statement(s) inside of a Try/Except that can be executed simultaneously?

Tags: python, physics, astronomy

```
try:
    for i,time in enumerate(times):
        sim.integrate(time)
            code a #calculates componants of planet 1&2
            code b #calculates....... 2&3
            code c #calculates....... 3&4
            code d #calculates....... 4&5
#where a - b are running simultaneously
except rebound.Encounter as error:
    print(error)
```

I'm running an integration throughout a finite amount time of where codes a-d are calculating coordinates of celestial bodies(planets). Once an adjacent pair of planets gets too close for comfort, the exception will come up, printing my error. I just need to make sure that, before the exception appears, code a-d are all working at once so that I can use them to identify which two planets had the close encounter.

***Codes a-d will be stored into an array of pointers and will change as the simulation is running.
What kind of loop/statement could I use that executes each code at the same time until the error is encountered?***

If you're curious, `sim` is a Rebound(an N-body integrator, i.e. a software package that can integrate the motion of particles under the influence of gravity.) variable where I store information about my planetary system.

http://rebound.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ipython/CloseEncounters.html The example I'm attempting to follow, only involves a two-planet system.

Comment: Did I miss the question?

Comment: No, I did, editing right now!

Comment: Could you not save the most recently calculated planets in variables and then just call upon those variables after the try/except? Also, why is the closeness of the planets throwing an exception? Why not just calculate distance between?

Comment: Codes a-d are my variables that I wish to call on. The exception is used to end the simulation. I've thought about calculating the distances between each adjacent planet pair throughout the simulation then plotting once finished, but I'm not sure that's the best way to find which two planets had the encounter. My end goal is to have thousands of these simulations running, and it would take too much time to look at thousands of these plots.

Comment: Executing statements simultaneously is probably not actually a good idea for your use case.

Comment: Why so? I've also considered 4 try and except statements all with differing try statements, but I don't necessarily think that will work.

Comment: You don't need to have things run simultaneously to handle them with the same try-except.

Comment: `rebound.Encounter` will trigger the close encounter between the planets. Until then, I need codes a-d to run simultaneously to figure out which planets had the close encounter, since they are being stored in an array.

Comment: So, when you have 1000s of these things running, you want them all to be running at the same time? I'm a little weary about ending a simulation on an exception, seems to be very bad practice. Exceptions should be used to catch unforeseen events in your code, not as conditional paths.

Comment: 17,500 to be exact. Yes, I want them all to update simultaneously. The orbits of the planets will change throughout time, and codes a-b will monitor that keeping them up to date in an array. The exception catches the unforeseen event (close encounter), which is when I want my simulation to end.